# How can I select a child "a, span" but limit which span using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following:

```
a = li.parent().parent().children('a, span');
```

I have a loop set up which starts with a link and goes up the chain.
If I understand this correctly then the code above selects a link if there is a span 
following it. Therefore it correctly selects:

```
   <a ..>..<span>History</span> .. </a> and
   <a ..>..<span>Overview</span> .. </a>
```

However I do not want it to select:

```
   <a ..> ..<span class="toggle"></span>
```

From the following HTML:

```
<ul id="menu" class="arbo with-title">
   <li>
      <a class="title-a">
         <span>Overview</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <span class="toggle"></span>
            <a class="folder"><span>Background</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a data-href="/History" class="document-web"><span>History</span></a></li>
               <li><a data-href="/eatures" class="document-web"><span>Features</span></a></li>
               <li><a data-href="/Design-Goals" class="document-web"><span>Design Goals</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
```

Is there a way that I can make the select at the top of this question not
notice a span with the class of toggle? Something like:

```
a = li.parent().parent().children('a, span(only if the element does not have a class of togggle)');
```

FYI here's the loop code:

```
function populateBreadcrumb(a: JQuery, $breadcrumb: JQuery) {
  while (a.length > 0) {
     $breadcrumb.prepend('<li><a >'+a.html()+'</a></li>');
     var li = a.parent();
     a = li.parent().parent().children('a, span');
  }
}
```

Comment: "the code above selects a link if there is a span following it". No. It selects all `a`'s and all `span`s

Comment: @Jan - Can you explain how the code works. If it selects all the a's and span's then will the while ever end ?

Comment: It selects all `a`'s and `span`s that exist at the moment of selection. Subsequently created `a`'s and `span`s are not added to the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the `:not` selector:

```
a = li.parent().parent().children("a, span:not(.toggle)");
```

This should do the trick.

Though you might want to use `find` instead of `children` to get all spans:

```
$("#menu").find("a, span:not(.toggle)");
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mGv6N/

Answer (score 0):

```
a = li.parent().parent().children('a, span:not('.toggle')"));
```

use the `not` selector with the specified class